# SQL: оптимальный запрос на получение данных и количества строк

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация, count

Пусть дана таблица с сотнями тысяч строк и строковыми столбцами. Также, дано условие выборки строк (это условие может содержать несколько сравнений строк). Необходимо вернуть как количество удовлетворяющих запросу строк, так и первые несколько строк. Как это можно сделать оптимально?
Используемая СУБД: Oracle 12c.

Я нашел один способ (ответ Jeffrey Kemp на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187124/how-to-select-all-columns-and-a-count-in-the-same-query), но, может, кто подскажет лучше?

PS: Уточнил версию Oracle. При выборке также должна выполняться сортировка -- этот момент я забыл уточнить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так попробовать:

```
with vtab as (
    select
        t.*,
        count(*) over() as cnt,
        row_number() over(order by col1) as rn
    from table_name t
    where ...
)
select col1, col2, col3, ..., cnt
from vtab
where rn <= 10;
```

Для Oracle версий 12.1+ можно воспользоваться [новой "фичей"](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1#paging):

```
with vtab as (
    select
        t.*,
        count(*) over() as cnt,
    from table_name t
    where ...
)
select col1, col2, col3, ..., cnt
from vtab
order by ...
OFFSET :v_offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :v_next ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: @Mike, что-то мне подсказывает , что это нужно для листания (pagination)...

Comment: @MaxU, да, для листания. Сейчас попробую

Comment: @MaxU, пока что не заметил повышения скорости по сравнению с ответом Jeffrey Kemp. Но как минимум на уровне.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, какая у вас версия Oracle?

Comment: @MaxU, Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit)

Comment: @MaxU, OFFSET и FETCH дали небольшой прирост около 10%

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, для того чтобы попытаться настроить "по-максимуму" надо видеть условие (WHERE CLAUSE) запроса, все индексы, как распределены данные, кардинальность, селективность, index clustering factors и т.д. Т.е. обычно для этого надо иметь доступ к данным, чтобы можно было сравнить планы выполнения запросов

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь с **Mike**, функции ROW_NUMBER() и COUNT(*)OVER() здесь избыточны. За исключением случаев, когда фильтрация данных настолько дорогостояща, что лучше выполнить её 1 раз, нежели два. Но если запрос идёт по индексам, попробуйте следующий вариант:

```
select rownum as rn, p.*, t.qty
from
(
  select count(*) as qty
  from table_name
  where ...
) t
cross /* left */ join
(
  select *
  from table_name p
  where ...
  -- order by ...
) p
where (rownum <= 10)
```

Для любого из проверяемых вариантов запроса проверяйте план выполнения. И реальное время исполнения, если объём данных позволяет адекватные замеры.

Comment: Спасибо, но конкретно в моей ситуации (я использую сортировку) этот запрос существенно (в 2 раза) медленнее, чем запрос, предложенный @MaxU

Comment: Я говорил лишь про избыточность row_number(), но ни в коем случае не о count() over(), ибо оптимизатор гораздо чаще решает его выполнить одновременно с основной выборкой, в отличие от отдельно написанного count() в подзапросе, поторый с большой вероятностью будет выполнен за отдельный проход по данным

Comment: Mike, прошу прощения, я чуток напутал

Answer (score 0):

Коль вопрос стал популярен, добавлю свой ответ (не уверен, что он сработает на 12й версии, но для 19й работает): если точность кол-ва строк не сильно важна, то для Oracle можно использовать функцию [approx_count](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/APPROX_COUNT.html#GUID-7D07E04A-3F9A-425E-BADE-EDA9C6162E9C). Есть ещё функция APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT, но она работает медленнее, и не всегда подходит. Зато она включена ещё в oracle 11g.

в итоге можно сделать 2 SQL-запроса (но возможно, выполнение одного запроса будет столь же эффективно):

```
SELECT department_id, job_id, 
   APPROX_COUNT(*) 
FROM   employees
GROUP BY department_id, job_id
HAVING 
  APPROX_RANK ( 
  PARTITION BY department_id 
  ORDER BY APPROX_COUNT(*) 
  DESC ) <= 10;
```

и

```
select department_id, job_id from my_table order by department_id where rownum <= 10
```

Комментарий относительно with из ответа выше: вложенные select могут работать очень медленно. Поэтому к with я тоже отношусь очень настороженно.

Для других СУБД для вычисления примерного кол-ва можно использовать план запроса и другие хаки, но это не всегда помогает.

PS: на практике скорость запросов лучше проверить перед использованием.